# drawing gradient over rectangle in swift

Tags: ios, swift, draw, gradient

I try to draw a gradient in a rectangle. 
Following picture shows, that gradient in general works (blue), but it fills the entire screen.

I like to do the gradient only in a specific area like the green rectangle.

How can I do this ?

[image]

My code for the gradient experiment :-)

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

//let locations: [CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 ]
let locations: [CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 0.99 ]

let colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor,
               UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]

let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace,
    colors, locations)

var startPoint = CGPoint()
var endPoint =  CGPoint()

startPoint.x = 0.0
startPoint.y = 10.0
endPoint.x = self.frame.width-100;
endPoint.y = 10

//let rectangle_main = CGRectMake(CGFloat(15), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(1000), CGFloat(30));

//CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a clipping path right before drawing the gradient.
In your case, create a rectangle path and call `CGContextClip(context)`

```
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRect(...))
CGContextClip(context)

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)
```

The gradient will be clipped to the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I searched for !